# Is there a better way to loop through six ranges?

Tags: python

I have code that looks like this:

```
for p in range(15):
    for q in range(5):
        for d in range(3):
            for sp in range(3):
                for sd in range(2):
                    for sq in range(2):
                        ...
```

It's going to use those six numbers to build two sets of tuples (`foo = my_func(x=(p,d,q), y=(sp,sd,sq))`) that get passed to a function in order to test the rests each time and find the best results for a given set of six parameters. What I have above will work, but maybe there's a more compact way to do it, perhaps with an external library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

ranges = [range(15), range(5), range(3), range(3), range(2), range(2)]
for p, q, d, sp, sd, sq in product(*ranges):
    ...
```